Can limit of ratio of functions at some point, which values at that point are non-zero be considered?
In my book it is stated:

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are infinitely small functions at $ _{x->x_0} $.

There is actually no definition of what infinitely small function is, but there is a definition of infinitely big function $f(x)$ at $x->x_0$ - if $\lim_{x->x_0}f(x)=\infty$, so I assume, that infinitely small at $x->x_0$ is, if $\lim_{x->x_0}f(x)=0$
Next,

If $\lim_{x->x_0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ then $f(x)$ is called an infinitely small of higher order, relatively to $g(x)$, often marked as $f = o(g)$.


If $\lim_{x->x_0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$ then $g(x)$ is called an infinitely small of higher order, relatively to $f(x)$, often marked as $g = o(f)$.

So, according to it, $f(x)=x^3$ is $f=o(g)$ to $g(x)=x^2$ at $x->0$.
But what if I want to compare functions at same limit point, that have same finite limit at that limit point, but non-zero?
As I understand, in case of $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^2$ at $x \in (-\infty, -1] ∪ [1, \infty)$ we should get $g=o(f)$, because $\forall a,b,c \in (0,1) \space a * b=c: c<a,c<b$ (multiplying 2 any numbers from 0 to 1 gives a number, that is smaller than both at all) and $\forall a \in (-\infty,-1)∪(1,\infty)\space a*a=c: c>a$ (power of number bigger than 1 (absolute value) gives bigger number).

Updating the question to indicate, that I am still would appreciate an answer

I'm guessing these are translations into English, so FYI it's probably better translated as "infinitely", not "infinitively". Not a huge issue, but it just makes a question look nicer.

Hmm, I noticed that in your other question you also used it as an adjective - which is okay, that happens in English a lot. But the word "infinitive" is very much a word from grammar, and I've never seen it used in proper written mathematics. That said, you seem to be working with a text that takes a different approach than I am used to, so they might have intentionally decided to use that specific term. But if, as I've guessed, you are the one translating into English, then yes, use "infinitely" instead of "infinitively".

@JonathanZ, changed

Definition ...
$$
f(x) = o(g(x)) \quad\text{ as }\quad x \to x_0
$$
is defined to mean
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 .
$$
So, in your case, if
$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$ both exist and are nonzero,
then $f(x) = o(g(x))$ is false.

You could perhaps usefully write
$$
f(x) - f(x_0) = o\big(g(x) - g(x_0)\big)
$$
so that $f(x)$ converges to $f(x_0)$ more rapidly than $g(x)$ converges to $g(x_0)$.

"...is defined to mean" - yes, this is why I am asking, what if I want to compare functions that has non-zero limits? Can I in the same way take the limit of their ratio, but $f(x)$ will be consider "infinitely small of higher order" then, if the absolute value of the limit of the such ratio will be bigger than $1$, if equal to $1$, then it would mean, that functions have same order, and if less than $1$ then $g(x)$ has higher order?
